# Edit XML node  with linguistic parsing - Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax, stanford-nlp

I hope someone can help me: first of all, I'm still a newbie with Java, but slowly improving, I guess.

So, I have an XML file with linguistic annotations and I would like to access a specific node to a) perform a pattern-matching operation on it and b) perform further operations on the matches

this a sample of the text, showing the node:

```
  <token id="13">
        <word>.</word>
        <lemma>.</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>57</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>58</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>.</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
    </tokens>
    <parse>(ROOT (S (NP (DT The) (NN world)) (VP (VBZ owes) (NP (DT all)) (NP (NP (NP (PRP$ its) (ADJP (RB onward) (NP (NNS impulses)) (PP (TO to))) (NNS men)) (ADJP (RB ill))) (PP (IN at) (NP (NN ease))))) (. .))) </parse>
    <basic-dependencies>
      <dep type="det">
        <governor idx="2">world</governor>
        <dependent idx="1">The</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="3">owes</governor>
        <dependent idx="2">world</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="iobj">
        <governor idx="3">owes</governor>
        <dependent idx="4">all</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="poss">
        <governor idx="9">men</governor>
        <dependent idx="5">its</dependent>
      </dep>
```

(So here, I have some linguistic annotations of a text, such as some tokens, Parts-of-Speech(POS), Named Entity Recognition(NER), and a syntactic/dependency parsing. This is actually the output of Stanford CoreNLP toolkit applied to a text..didn't add the whole file because it's huge)

My question is: according to what I've been reading, it seems to be that StaX parser is a good away to access the file and produce a new one with my operations. Is this right? My question also includes, can I do a pattern-match operation with StaX?

A thousand thanks in advance.

Comment: I only see one XML element: `parse`. What is the meaning and structure of the nested `()` pairs?

Comment: specifically, these nested pairs represent the syntactic structure of a sentence, like Noun Phrase (NP), Verb Phrase(VP), Noun (NN) and so on. I'll post a bigger sample of the XML code above.

Comment: @SophieM -- Yes, but it's not XML. XML elements look like so: `<elementName></elementName>`. The parentheticals are not XML elements.

Comment: It looks like `scheme` notation, which I believe can be converted to xml, though not by anything in Java SE that I know of. Will peek around the internet for libraries if any, and will get back if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(ROOT ...)` is in a format called S-expression. Anything in the Java SE will not be able to parse it, so you will have to do something else.

Of course you have to use StAX (or something else) to parse the xml file. That way you will get hold of the above strings, as strings. You will have to run another parser over these strings to get their structures.

A preliminary google search gave me
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/S-Expressions#Java which is based on
http://jfkbits.blogspot.jp/2008/05/thoughts-on-s-expression-parser.html.
But you can yourself use the search terms like "S-expression parser in Java" and review first few results to see what suits you.

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice I am answering a question of 2012!